# "This question may already have an answer here" - how to deny?

Tags: support, possible-duplicates

On my [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68888/an-obvious-problem-or-a-obvious-problem), I noticed a box saying

> This question may already have an answer here:
>       [a / an - adjective - noun](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43475/a-an-adjective-noun)  1 answer

As this is not a duplicate, I clicked *No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.* and did exactly that. I just returned to find the box reappearing even though I added that explanation.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a comment claiming that your question is a duplicate, you can flag that comment after you make your edit. Select the button that says *obsolete*. That way, a moderator will look at question and make a decision.

Another way is to address the issue is by using a meta question, as you did here. That way, people can see the question here in meta and then go investigate.

In this case, I think you might be the only one seeing the box. I can't see it. If you can still see it, evidently, the Stack Exchange leaves it there. If you can't still see it, maybe it takes some time between when you make your edit and when it disappears.

Comment: Probably the third paragraph applied, it's gone now :-)

Comment: Once you've edited, the question will either still be closed (if your edits were insufficient) or the existing votes/flags will age away in a few days (along with the banner).

Comment: @Shog9 - *if your edits were insufficient...* I'm curious: How is that determination made?

Comment: The folks reading the question either still think it's a duplicate and vote accordingly, or don't @J.R.